# How to change text with icon with css or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change number(text) "1" in my form (gravity form) with star icon:

https://fontawesome.com/icons/star?style=regular

It must go sth like that i guess:

```
<script>
$("#label_13_5_0").text(function () {
    return $(this).attr("1").text().replace("1", "star");
});
</script>
```

This does not work

My website (u can see number in my form that heas to be replaced with stars):

http://online.pravneresitve.si/anketa-o-zdavoljstvu/

Comment: You're getting "typeError $ is not a function" - as though you weren't including jQuery in your page?

Comment: Also, this `replace("1", "star");` is just replacing the string "1" with a string "star".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this, but i  think you'll need to install fa icons

```
<script>
$("#label_13_5_0").text(function () {
    return $(this).text("<i class='far fa-star'></i>");
});
</script>
```

but to your example:

```
<script>
$("#label_13_5_0").text(function () {
    return $(this).text("star");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- include fontawesome in your html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />



// --------------------------------------------------------
//
//  1) loop through the labels 
//  2) get the text and convert it to number
//  3) create a string to hold the replacement html
//  4) make a while loop based on the number and add 
//     <i class="fa fa-star"></i> to the string on each 
//     loop the num-- will subtract one from number on
//     each loop and cause it to stop at zero
//  5) replace the innerHTML with the icon markup
//
// -------------------------------------------------------- 
$('label', '.gfield_radio').each(function(){   
    var num = Number(this.innerText);               
    var str = '';
    while(num--) str+='<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
    this.innerHTML = str;
});
```